# How do I unit test an AngularJS controller that relies on a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, promise

In my controller, I have:

```
  $scope.index = function() {
    CompanyService.initialized.then(function() {
      var company_id = CompanyService.getCompany()._id;
      LocationService.list(company_id, $routeParams.location_parent_id).then(function(response) {
        if(response.data.status === 'ok') {
          $scope.locations = response.data.locations;
          $scope.current_location = response.data.location || null;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

So it should get the `LocationService` list and the test is as follows:

```
it('should get locations', function() {
  $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/v1/location/list').respond({status: 'ok', locations: ['loc1', 'loc2']})
  $scope.index();
  expect($scope.locations.length).toEqual(2);
```

However, this never happens, because `CompanyService` has a promise that never gets resolved in the unit test. How do I either mock the returned promise of `CompanyService` or bypass it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply mock the call using  `createSpyObj` method from Jasmine:

```
describe('one test', function(){

 var deferred, CompanyService, $scope;

 beforeEach(inject(function ($q, $rootScope, $controller) {
  params = {
        $scope: $rootScope.$new(),
        CompanyService = jasmine.createSpyObj('CompanyService', ['initialized'])
  }
  params.CompanyService.initialized.andCallFake(function () {
      deferred = $q.defer();
      return deferred.promise;  //will fake to return a promise, in order to reach it inside the test
    });
  $controller('YourController', params);
 });

 it('my test', function(){
     deferred.resolve({}); //empty object returned for the sample but you can set what you need to be returned
     $scope.$digest(); //important in order to resolve the promise
    //at this time, the promise is resolved! so your logic to test can be placed here
 });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'deferred.resolve')`

Comment: @Shamoon I made an update, are you using the exact the same code? Make sure the `deferred` variable is reachable in your test, as the code shows.

Comment: How do I use the `$injector` set up to accomplish this? I'm using http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/12/13/how-to-unit-test-controllers-in-angularjs-without-setting-your-hair-on-fire/ as the baseline for my testing

Comment: @Shamoon No need to explicitly use the `$injector`. But if you really want it, you can do as follows: `beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope'); // .......`

Comment: Right, I get how to get the `$rootScope`, etc with the `$injector`, but what about this spy business?

Comment: @Shamoon This is totally independent of the spy business, you can keep the same code.

Comment: I'm instantiating my controller in my test: https://gist.github.com/shamoons/e62d9e202cebb867211b

Comment: @Shamoon Just make `$controller` as an injected variable, just updated my code. I made a comment on your gist

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48080/discussion-between-shamoon-and-mik378)

Comment: I think there's a syntax error in what you have: `        CompanyService = jasmine.createSpyObj('CompanyService', ['initialized']);
` in params is weird having an `=` and ending with a `;`

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: Add `$scope.$apply();` after calling `$scope.$index();`.

**Long answer:** Your problem is probably due to the way $q propagates promises resolution. Indeed resolution only happens when $digest is performed. I don't know why $digest is not performed during tests whereas it is during regular use, but this solution is suggested anyway in the Angular documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q .

What's more you could directly use `$scope.$digest();` in your case instead of `$scope.$apply();` since $apply is only a wrapper that runs any function passed to it before calling $digest.