# Jasmine. Angular Services. Angular Promises. How to make them play together?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-runner

I was following [this example](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/12/unit-testing-services-in-angularjs-for-fun-and-for-profit/).

We have test suite like:

```
describe('Basic Test Suite', function(){
    var DataService, httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module('iorder'));
    beforeEach(inject(
        function (_DataService_, $httpBackend) {
            DataService = _DataService_;
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        }
    ));
    //And following test method:
    it('should call data url ', function () {
        var promise = DataService.getMyData();
        promise.then(function(result) { 
            console.log(result, promise); // Don't gets here
        }).finally(function (res) {  
            console.log(res); // And this is also missed
        })
    })
});
```

How to make jasmine + karma work with angular services, that returns promise?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081586/unit-test-promise-based-code-in-angular), but looks like it's about using promises in test cases. Not about testing promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell jasmine that your test is asynchronous so that it waits for the promises to resolve.  You do this by adding a `done` parameter to your test:

```
describe('Basic Test Suite', function(){
    var DataService, httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module('iorder'));
    beforeEach(inject(
        function (_DataService_, $httpBackend) {
            DataService = _DataService_;
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        }
    ));
    //And following test method:
    it('should call data url ', function (done) {
        var promise = DataService.getMyData();
        promise.then(function(result) { 
            console.log(result, promise); // Don't gets here
            done();//this is me telling jasmine that the test is ended
        }).finally(function (res) {  
            console.log(res); // And this is also missed
            //since done is only called in the `then` portion, the test will timeout if there was an error that by-passes the `then`
        });
    })
});
```

By adding `done` to the test method, you are letting jasmine know that it is an asynchronous test and it will wait until either `done` is called, or a timeout.  I usually just put a call to `done` in my `then` and rely on a timeout to fail the test.  Alternatively, I believe you can call `done` with some kind of error object which will also fail the test, so you could call it in the `catch`.

Comment: Yeah, passing argument to function to make test async - most clear way :) Thx. :)