# How to validate mock response in karma jasmine unit testing

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I need to validate the response after success and error states of a service. My service as belows.

```
   vm.onSupportFileDeleted = function (file) {
        DocumentService.deleteDocument(file.fileId).then(function () {
            var index = vm.supportingDocuments.indexOf(file);
            vm.supportingDocuments.splice(index, 1);
            vm.dzRemoveFile(file);
            setSupportFileStatusA11yAlert('Document removed');
            //advanced-options-link
            angular.element('#advanced-options-link').trigger('focus');
        }, function (msg) {
            $log.error('Document not deleted - ' + JSON.stringify(msg));
            showSupportingDocumentError('Unable to delete file');
            setSupportFileStatusA11yAlert('Unable to remove document');
        });

    };
```

I need to validate index, supportingDocuments variables.
I have created a mock as below.

```
            DocumentServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('DocumentService', [
            'deleteDocument'
        ]);
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have created a spy object but not a mock response, what you want to do is create a spy that returns a mock value.

You want to mock the response from your promise and make assertions (expect) on resolve (**then**) and on reject(**error**).

There are examples in this thread [Unit-test promise-based code in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081586/unit-test-promise-based-code-in-angular)